# external .js variable coming back undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I am trying to get an external .js variable into my index.html however the variable just comes back undefined. It works if the variable is in the HTML file but not when I call it from an outside .js file it just reads undefined ?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />

    <title>LoginSystem</title>

    <script src="../server.js"></script>

</head>    
<body>

    <div id="display"></div>

    <script>
        var t = setInterval(function() {
            // you can change `random` to any variable you want to be displayed

            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = random;

        }, 500);
    </script>    
</body>
```

and the javascript file

```
var random = Math.random();
```

any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: are you sure that server.js is loaded?

Comment: I believe so if i delete var random = Math.random(); it just shows nothing  as if it sees the variable but thinks it is not defined? The div display reads undefined with it.

Comment: Add a console log or an alert to the js file and check if that is executed.

Comment: Look in the network tab if server.js is loaded , theres nothing wrong with the code , regards

Comment: I ran an alert to see if the function was running and it showed up so it is running just not defined but it works when inside the same file so I am lost I dunno.

Comment: Please check the server.js is loaded properly or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain why you're getting `undefined`; however, Since you set `random` in a variable outside of the scope of the function passed into `setInterval`, it will always display the same random number. You need to set `random` inside the function passed to `setInterval` if you want a new random number to show up.

#### server.js

```
function getRandomNumber() {
  return Math.random();
}
```

#### index.html

```
var t = setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = getRandomNumber();
}, 500);
```

## Demo

https://repl.it/@AnonymousSB/RemarkableBowedNagware

Comment: Since you confirmed the path is correct, I've updated my answer with what I suspect is the issue.

Comment: i keep getting this i made a test.js in the same folder and it errors Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:3000/test.js”.

Comment: What server are you using? Express? Sounds like there might be a configuration issue.

Comment: i moved the test.js back one to where the server.js was and set <script type="text/javascript" src="../test.js"></script> it worked so I dunno X)

Answer (score 1):

i think you may be looking in the wrong directory for your server.js see this line:

```
 <script src="../server.js"></script>
```

Make sure the file path is correct, if your index and server.js are in the same fodler it should be:

```
<script src="./server.js"></script>
```

I have tested the same code and it works perfectly for me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Youu external javascript file path isn't correct. Replace `../server.js` with `/server.js`